# 0..1 to many relationship with Fluent API with EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I need to declare an 0..1 to many relationship using Fluent API with EntityFramework Core. Right now I have a 1 to many relationship and I cannot figure out how to change that to a 0..1 to many.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
      .HasOne(c => c.Constraint)
      .WithMany(p => p.Constraint)
      .HasForeignKey(p => p.Growid)
      .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.Growid);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#required):

> If you have a foreign key property in your entity class then the requiredness of the relationship is determined based on whether the foreign key property is required or optional

[Further information](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/required-optional.html):

> A property is considered optional if it is valid for it to contain null. If null is not a valid value to be assigned to a property then it is considered to be a required property.

Therefore, in order to change the nature of the relationship from required (1 to many) to a 0 .. 1 to many, you need to make the foreign key nullable. You do that in the domain entity:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Item Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ForeignKeyItemId { get; set; }
    public ForeignKeyItem ForeignKeyItem { get; set; }
}
```